# How to prevent <Python.h> of Python 2.7 from including <inttypes.h> in a Python wrapper generated by SWIG?

Tags: python, c++, swig

I am developing a C++ library in which SWIG is used to generate its Python wrapper. Some of my C++ files use `<inittypes.h>` to call PRId64 and other macros in sprintf.

I was able to compile my library with Python 2.6 and GCC 4.4.7 on Scientific Linux 6 (RHEL6 clone), but Python 2.7 and GCC 4.8.2 on Scientific Linux 7 (RHEL7 clone) generated many errors like below.

```
/home/oxon/libTARGET/inc/target/T2EvalBoard.h:562:145: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
 In file included from /home/oxon/libTARGET_build/src/targetPYTHON_wrap.cxx:3117:0:
/home/oxon/libTARGET/inc/target/BaseCameraModule.h: In member function ‘virtual void TARGET::BaseCameraModule::ReceiveEvent(uint32_t&, uint8_t**)’:
/home/oxon/libTARGET/inc/target/BaseCameraModule.h:211:66: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘PRIu32’
     sprintf(str, "Cannot read event data. Requested length is %" PRIu32 " bytes, but only %" PRId64 " bytes were read.", length, fBytesReturned);
```

I know that I have to add the following lines in header files first in order to use `PRId64` and other.

```
#define __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS
#include <inttypes.h>
```

But `targetPYTHON_wrap.cxx`, which is a source file generated by SWIG, includes `<Python.h>` in the beginning of the file, and so the above lines are ignored. Indeed, the following code cannot be compiled, because `<Python.h>` includes `<inttypes.h>` in it.

```
#include <Python.h>

#define __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS
#include <inttypes.h>

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("Output: " PRIu32 "\n", 100);
  return 0;
}
```

How do I use `PRId64` and other macros with `<Python.h>` and SWIG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SWIG, the following adds lines to the very top of the SWIG wrapper, so it will be defined before `Python.h`:

```
%begin %{
#define __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS
#include <inttypes.h>
%}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added `-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS` in `CXX_FLAGS`, but looking for a better solution if exists.